# CentOS 7 Root Logical Volume Being Checked Every boot

Tags: boot, centos-7, xfs

The boot time of my CentOS 7 system is being severely slowed down because FS checks are being performed EVERY time:

```
 Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Found device /dev/mapper/cl-root.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/mapper/cl-root...
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/mapper/cl-root.
[  127.516469] dracut-initqueue[261]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
.....
  189.331811] dracut-initqueue[261]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
     Mounting /sysroot...
```

My FSTAB entry:

```
/dev/mapper/cl-root     /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
```

The FS check takes a minute to complete.

How can I prevent FS checks being performed every boot?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why your disk would be checked every time at boot.

Usually this is because the disk has errors, and you have yet to fix them.  Boot-time scans cannot always fix errors, and will just report that human-intervention is required.

It is also possible to set a flag on the volume to scan every time.  Check `tune2fs`... specifically the `-c` flag.

Setting the "fsck.mode=force" as a kernel boot option can force a check every boot... perhaps someone/something updated the boot options.

I have seen where the "forcefsck" file in the root is re-created by a process running on the machine, but this is more of a "slight-possibility" than a likely.

Comment: tune2fs isn't going to work for an XFS filesystem